# What type of code or program , i can post as open source on Git or Bit Bucket

Tags: programming-languages, open-source

I have seen many times that if you want to look good on resumes  you should have some project coded as open source on bit bucket and Git.

I want to do that , even though it may be small but at least i want to starts the steps which can make me a good programmer and it looks good on resume.

I knows these languages like `php bash python django jquery joomla`

Can anyone give me some example what type of projects i should upload there which i can mention in resume. i usually build websites , how can i put those type of codes.

Does putting shell script for backing database can also be put in there

Comment: django, jquery and joomla aren't even languages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excellent initiative on wanting to get involve. However, I would suggest researching a project that is already on-going and contribute towards that.

If you start a new project on GitHub, SourceForge or BitBucket, it will be most likely have a team member of 1 (you). The problem is not that your project is not open sourced, but that you are the only one working on it.

If a job candidate tells me they are involve in an open source project, I would look at the project for some of the following characteristics.

- **size of the code base**, a large code base shows that you can handle a project will some complexity in functionality and implementation.
- **size of the project team**, it indicates that you can work in a team successfully with good communication skills with your team members. Also how you interact with their programming styles.
- **code quality**, the quality of your contribution has good comments, nicely structured, working on code from others
- **time spent on project**, shows that you have commitment with define start and end points.

Being a contributor does not necessary contributing to the code. You could contribute to up keeping of the documentation, or do some translation.

My point being is that everything that you do in this space is valuable to your resume, but **do it with a team**.

Answer (score 7):

**Anything!**

You can place *anything* on an open-source web host (e.g. GitHub, BitBucket, SourceForge, etc.). You can write a diary and upload by committing changes to it every minute if you so desired.

*Note: Joomla is not a programming language. Neither is Django. And neither is jQuery.*

However, in order to following the rest of the programming community, the norm is to break down work into projects. These projects will contain code/images/whatever that is relevant to the work. Within each of these projects, you want to:

- Ensure your code is well documented.
- Organise the code repository in a sensible manner.
- Tidy the miscellaneous parts around the project - ensure it is *obvious* what your project is about; ensure it is *easy* for those to contribute (if it's open for contribution).

People view open-source projects as an action of *giving back* to the community so by following these steps above, you will appear selfless and, subsequently, professional. This will yield big browny points on your resume.

Comment: Good point about giving back.  It also shows something of your motivation to code.

Comment: @Jonathan are there any examples of simple project so that i can see how people have done it. Does it has to be unique or i can upload my personal python backup script there. Although there can be more advanced scripts as well on internet. Why will someone look at it

Answer (score 0):

Post your strongest work that emphasizes your skills in fundamental areas (knowing how to write secure software, effective database integration), and "link" those to skills on your resume.

That way, even if the project is in a language/platform/framework that is not being used by a particular company, they will recognize that you know your stuff, and would (presumably) be able to adapt what you know to their particular project.

Answer (score 0):

Post project you worked on more than a few hours, with a great number of lines of code. Projects which can be improved, not simple codes like printing a stream of Fibonacci numbers.

Also, if it is possible, consider creating at least a Readme in which you explain what the code does. Better will be to have a Changelist, a TODO list and a wiki. And keep track on the issues tab :)